# Does Razr i connect to PEAP protected wi-fi networks?

Tags: wi-fi, motorola-razr-i

I have tried to connect to a "eduroam" network (PEAP) but it did not work in my Motorola Razr i, Android 4.0.4 . Any tips?

Comment: What's eduroam? IIRC there's WEP/WPA/WPA2 PSK and 802.1x EAP.... but no PEAP...

Comment: Could you please add a few more details? Like t0mm13b there, I've heard of peep and popp (oh, different topic, sorry) -- but neither of eduroam nor peap. A link to some specs might also be helpful. We really like to help, please give us a chance :)

Comment: "This is the configuration manual of the wireless network of the univerisity I study (eduroam): http://www.cbc.ufms.br/Biblioteca/servicos/manuais/ab15cac17b50ceddeac1f739a3ee73c3.pdf . In page #3 there's an image of the network's security method selection screen, in this case PEAP, to be used in my Razr i. But I can't find this method listed in my phone so I can't connect it to the network. Could you please help me?"

Comment: I've only heard of it in the context of Microsoft but it looks like it's more broad than I realized: [Protected Extensible Authentication Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protected_Extensible_Authentication_Protocol).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same phone and got it to work on eduroam just now (was actually googling for solutions when I managed to solve it myself).  Was your problem also that you couldn't find the right part of the settings?  Weirdly you need to first just try to connect any old how (so it's saved as a network you use) and then long-press on it and choose "modify network".  This time you get a much longer list of options and can choose PEAP etc as in the university instructions -- at least, my university instructions work (http://www.oucs.ox.ac.uk/network/wireless/services/eduroam/android/) and I believe the point of the network is that you only need to set it up once.

However I'm already on the 4.1.2 update.  If you still can't get on you could check if the OTA is available for you yet (all settings -> about phone -> system updates).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my RAZR i (Android 4.0.4) and was able to solve it by installing [Wifi Connection Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.roamingsoft.manager).  Within the app, 802.1x PEAP is available for configuration.